# Create a v1 model from a v2 model

Tags: python, pydantic, langchain

I have a project that is using Pydantic v2. The project is also using LangChain which, as of today, [only supports Pydantic v1](https://python.langchain.com/docs/guides/pydantic_compatibility).

Instead of converting my entire project to Pydantic v1, or else having a mix of v1 and v2 models in the project, I had the idea that whenever I pass a Pydantic model to LangChain, I can simply convert the v2 model to a v1 model.

NOTE: It is the model schema which must be converted, not an instance of the model.

How can I achieve this?

It would look something like this:

```py
from langchain.chains import create_tagging_chain_pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel as BaseModelV2
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel as BaseModelV1

class TaggingModel(BaseModelV2):
    ...

def convert_to_v1(v2_model: type[BaseModelV2]) -> type[BaseModelV1]:
    ...

chain = create_tagging_chain_pydantic(pydantic_schema=convert_to_v1(TaggingModel), llm=llm)
```

Comment: But your approach would require having Pydantic v1 and v2 installed in the same environment. This does not work.

Comment: v1 is included in the v2 package under pydantic.v1

Comment: Oh, I see. Langchain already allows to install Pydantic v2, but their model definitions are still at v1 (https://python.langchain.com/docs/guides/pydantic_compatibility#langchain-pydantic-migration-plan).

Comment: I would assume that JSON Schemas are compatible between Pydantic v1 and v2. So why not just use `create_tagging_chain(MyModelV2.model_json_schema(), ...)` instead and parse the result again as a Pydantic v2 model?